# Error with SUMPRODUCT code. I am getting #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to sum the range where the date is between two dates.

I tried with some simple data in separate sheet and i have not been successful .

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Open PO'!A:A=Summary!B273)*('Open PO'!K2:AQ2='Open PO'!K2:AQ2,">="&Summary!J2,'Open PO'!K2:AQ2,"<"&Summary!K2)*'Open PO'!K3:AQ166)
```

I like to see the range summed up without any error.

Comment: Why are you not using Sumifs? Can we see some sample data?

Comment: Kindly share the sample data.